# Inclosing \section in \vbox failed with: "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. }"

Tags: macros, environments, boxes

I wanna put some complex commands (e.g. `\section` and `\chapter`) inside a box (`\vbox`) so later I can compute the height of the block contains the text.

Here is the full example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\newsavebox{\samplebox}
\newcommand{\sampleboxcommand}[1]{
    \savebox{\samplebox}{#1}
    \usebox{\samplebox}
}
\begin{document}

\sampleboxcommand{
    \section{Section X}
    \subsection{Subsection Y}
}
\end{document}
```

But it gives me many errors like:

- `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. }`
- `Missing } inserted. }`
- `Too many }'s. }`

What's wrong with my code? If I replace the `\savebox` and `\usebox` with a simple `\vbox{#1}` everything goes smoothly.

Comment: you are using `\savebox` which is an `\hbox` not `\vbox` you can not have vertical material in an hbox.

Comment: you can use `\savebox{\samplebox}{\vbox{#1}}`

Answer (score 1):

Despite the `\vbox` in the question, you had used an `\hbox`. Section headings can not be used in horizontal mode contexts.

If you wrap the vertical mode material in a `\vbox` then it works without error.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\newsavebox{\samplebox}
\newcommand{\sampleboxcommand}[1]{%
    \savebox{\samplebox}{\vbox{#1}}%
    \noindent\usebox{\samplebox}%
}
\begin{document}

\sampleboxcommand{
    \section{Section X}
    \subsection{Subsection Y}
}
\end{document}
```